# How To Create a Custom Action for the Center Tab Bar Item

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rxjs

I want to show a modal from the button when the user clicks the button in center.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

On you tab screen

```
        <Tab.Screen name="modal" component={YourModalCompnent} />
```

YourModalComponent

```
             const dropdownRef = useRef<DropdownRef>(null);


        <Dropdown
      ref={dropdownRef}
      title={
        <Text>
          What did you do?
        </Text>
      }
      showSwipeIndicator={false}
      roundedTop="2xl"
    >
      <Dropdown.Option value={0}>
        <Div flex={1} alignItems="center">
          your modal content
        </Div>}
      </Dropdown.Option>
      <Dropdown.Option value={3} py="md" px="xl" block>
        <ButtononPress={() => dropdownRef.current?.close()}> close modal button</Button>
      </Dropdown.Option>
    </Dropdown>
```

reference I use modal from magnus UI and it is customizable. But you can use your own custom modal or any modal of your choice.. you can also have a state of the modal component is always open or you can pass it as a prop

Link to https://magnus-ui.com/